# Django - get user id from username

Tags: django

I would like to get user posts on a profile page.
My current code is:

```
# views.py

def show_blog(request, username):
# If username exists
if User.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
    # Get user data and rendert the page
    user_data = {'user': User.objects.get(username = username)}
    user_posts = {'posts': Post.objects.filter(author = user_data.id)}
    return render(request, "blogs/show_blog.html", user_data)

return HttpResponse(404)


# show_blog.html - later, I'll make it show user posts
<h1>@{{ user }}</h1>
<p>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
```

Now, the problem is this error:

```
AttributeError at /blogs/testuser/
'dict' object has no attribute 'id'
```

When I go to:

```
/blogs/testuser
```

Comment: Try to replace `user_data.id` by `user_data['user'].id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not work with `user_data.id`, since `user_data` is a dictionary that contains a `'user'` key, not the `User` object itself.

You can use `user` instead with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def show_blog(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    context = {
        'user': user,
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(author=user)
    }
    return render(request, 'blogs/show_blog.html', context)
```

You render the posts through iterating:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that .get could cause error 500.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use dictionary as queryset. Dictionary items are just key value pairs.

```
user = User.objects.get(username = username)
posts =  Post.objects.filter(author = user.id)
context = {'user':user,'user_posts':posts}
return render(request, "blogs/show_blog.html", context)
```

now you can do this in template

```
<h1>{{user.username}}</h1>
<p>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
<p>{{ user_posts.title }}</p>
```